# how to use javascript to pick up element in another website

Tags: javascript

I want to make a website which can fetch elements of another website. So my idea is to open an invisible window and pick some elements to display. How can I implement this with JavaScript?

As [Valeh Hajiyev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16640866/2361752) points out, it is impossible to achieve with client-side JS.

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to steal?

Comment: how's it fetched? what is the type of auth (Basic, custom token in header, OAuth). What elements are being grabbed.

Comment: For example, i want to make a website as an alternative of facebook, but i dobt use its API, i just simply make a page that can open the facebook in the backhround, then fill the password then pock up tje data I want selectively to display in the foreground. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with client-side JavaScript because of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Thank you. So I can't use JavaScript to open another site and fill the password and login then fetch the data. But during the process only the data fetched displayed?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to do this process in client-side. But you can do it in server-side even with JavaScript (nodejs).